# Why got FCM error when calling cloud function onCall

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I calling cloud function using onCall and get valid result but always got FCM error, that make current FCM token not valid and cannot receive notification again.

note : Not only for cloud function **generateJWTMessagingToken** but also for other cloud function that have not relation with FCM

Error :
[https://fcmregistrations.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{projectId}/registrations](https://fcmregistrations.googleapis.com/v1/projects/%7BprojectId%7D/registrations) |
POST | 401 Unauthorized.

[Image Error FCM 401](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktjh3.png)

firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.0/firebase-app.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.0/firebase-messaging.js");
```

package.json

```
{
    "firebase": "^9.22.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.4.1"
}
```

this is how I call in client side (React.js)

```
import { httpsCallable } from "firebase/functions";
import { functions } from "config/firebase";

const generateJWTMessagingToken = async () => {
    const onCall = httpsCallable(functions, "generateJWTMessagingToken");
    const responseOnCall: any = await onCall();
    return responseOnCall?.data?.token || "";
}

export default generateJWTMessagingToken;
```